# eBay API error : You have exceeded your maximum call limit

Tags: limit, ebay-api

I have a table of eBay `itemid`, and for each id I want to apply a `reviseitem` call, but from the second call I get the following error:

```
You have exceeded your maximum call limit of 3000 for 5 seconds. Try back after 5 seconds.
```

NB: I have just **4 calls**.
How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

ebay count the calls per second per unique IP's. So please make sure your all calls from your application must be less than 3000 per 5 seconds. hope this would help.

Answer (score 1):

I have just finished an eBay project and this error can be misleading.  eBay allow a certain amount of calla a day and if you exceed that amount in one 24 hour period you can get this error.  You can get this amount increased by completing an Application Check form  http://go.developer.ebay.com/developers/ebay/forums-support/certification

Answer (score 0):

The eBay Trading API, to which your ReviseItem call belongs, allows up to 5000 calls per 24 hour period for all applications, and up to 1.5M calls / 24hrs for "Compatible Applications", i.e. applications that have undergone a vetting process called "Compatible Application Check". More details here: https://go.developer.ebay.com/developers/ebay/ebay-api-call-limits

However, that's just the generic, "Aggregate" call limit. There are different limits for specific calls, some of which are more liberal (AddItem: 100.000 / day) and others of which are more strict (SetApplication: 50 / day) than that. Additionally, there are hourly and periodic limits.

You can find out any application's applicable limits by executing the GetApiAccessRules call:

```
  <GetApiAccessRulesResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
   <Timestamp>2014-12-02T13:25:43.235Z</Timestamp>
   <Ack>Success</Ack>
   <Version>889</Version>
   <Build>E889_CORE_API6_17053919_R1</Build>
   <ApiAccessRule>
    <CallName>ApplicationAggregate</CallName>
    <CountsTowardAggregate>true</CountsTowardAggregate>
    <DailyHardLimit>5000</DailyHardLimit>
    <DailySoftLimit>5000</DailySoftLimit>
    <DailyUsage>10</DailyUsage>
    <HourlyHardLimit>6000</HourlyHardLimit>
    <HourlySoftLimit>6000</HourlySoftLimit>
    <HourlyUsage>0</HourlyUsage>
    <Period>-1</Period>
    <PeriodicHardLimit>10000</PeriodicHardLimit>
    <PeriodicSoftLimit>10000</PeriodicSoftLimit>
    <PeriodicUsage>0</PeriodicUsage>
    <PeriodicStartDate>2006-02-14T07:00:00.000Z</PeriodicStartDate>
    <ModTime>2014-01-20T11:20:44.000Z</ModTime>
    <RuleCurrentStatus>NotSet</RuleCurrentStatus>
    <RuleStatus>RuleOn</RuleStatus>
   </ApiAccessRule>
   <ApiAccessRule>
    <CallName>AddItem</CallName>
    <CountsTowardAggregate>false</CountsTowardAggregate>
    <DailyHardLimit>100000</DailyHardLimit>
    <DailySoftLimit>100000</DailySoftLimit>
    <DailyUsage>0</DailyUsage>
    <HourlyHardLimit>100000</HourlyHardLimit>
    <HourlySoftLimit>100000</HourlySoftLimit>
    <HourlyUsage>0</HourlyUsage>
    <Period>-1</Period>
    <PeriodicHardLimit>0</PeriodicHardLimit>
    <PeriodicSoftLimit>0</PeriodicSoftLimit>
    <PeriodicUsage>0</PeriodicUsage>
    <ModTime>2014-01-20T11:20:44.000Z</ModTime>
    <RuleCurrentStatus>NotSet</RuleCurrentStatus>
    <RuleStatus>RuleOn</RuleStatus>
   </ApiAccessRule>
```

You can try that out four your own application by pasting an AuthToken for your application into the form at https://ebay-sdk.intradesys.com/s/9a1158154dfa42caddbd0694a4e9bdc8 and then press "Execute call".

HTH.